# Android Smsmanager not sending message more than once

Tags: android, android-permissions, smsmanager

I want to send message everytime I click  button but with this code I am able to send message only first time.I can only send message again when I clear App data and cache.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tapme;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 0;

String phoneNo;
String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tapme = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tapme);
    tapme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendSMS();
        }
    });


}

protected void sendSMS() {
    phoneNo = "+911333444400";
    message = "hi";

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where i do wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're only sending the SMS after successfully requesting the permission. Think about what happens if the permission is already granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   protected void sendSMS() {
        phoneNo = "1";
        message = "hi";

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);

        } else {
            SendTextMsg();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    SendTextMsg();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void SendTextMsg() {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```